# iOS calendar check in background

Tags: ios, background, calendar, push-notification

I would like my app to check on a date while running in the background.  At that point, I would like to do a local notification, but I know how to do that...  What I am interested in is, if somebody even clicks the home button, and my app is in the background, I would like my app to check what date it is (once a day, while in the background), and if it is a particular date, I would like to do a local notification - a sort of an app-specific calendar...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app (probably) doesn't run in the background so you cannot check the date, but you can schedule a local notification for a specific date (`fireDate`) with the following

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*90];  // the date you want the notification to fire.
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

For more info see [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post would be helpful for you http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-understanding-ios-4-multitasking/ . Good luck!